# How do I install kernel 2.6.35 in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, kernel

I have encountered a bug relating to stock kernel 2.6.32 in lucid, so I want to upgrade to 2.6.35. What is the simplest way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel team has [just announced](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2010-October/013218.html) a 2.6.35 backport for 10.04. Please note:

> While the primary incentive for the
>   backport effort has been server 
>   enablement, the desktop flavours will
>   work but your mileage may vary.  I've
>   successfully used -generic- on both
>   nVidia and Intel graphics GPUs  in 2D
>   mode. That being said, any bug reports
>   against the desktop  flavours will be
>   marked 'Wont Fix'. There is simply too
>   much skew  between Maverick DRM and
>   Lucid X server drivers.

According to the mail the packages mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5416/how-do-i-install-kernel-2-6-35-in-lucid/5462#5462) have been deleted.

Answer (score 6):

The ubuntu kernel team provides [mainline kernels in a ppa](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).

You can see a [complete list of versions available](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=A). The latest for Lucid appears to be [2.6.35-rc1-lucid](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.35-rc1-lucid/). That link goes to a directory where you can download deb files. Install them to install the kernel.

Comment: I tried to install the debs after downoading them but I faced dependency problems. Any particular order that they have to be installed?

Answer (score 2):

Add the Kernel-ppa to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu lucid main`

Then install the latest kernel with the command below, remember to replace  with the kernel type required for your system (typically generic, generic-pae, or server):

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-<flavour>-lts-backport-maverick`

Comment: I've fixed your formatting, I think this would be a better answer if you used add-apt-repository as outlined here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/4987#4987

Comment: Now that 10.10 has released these kernels have moved into Lucid proper and you no longer require a PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you are using proprietary drivers those will most probably not work. Also, ureadahead which is responsible for the speedy ubuntu boot will not work. Don't worry too much, it still boots fast but THAT FAST :)